# Why do I have "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0" when I load 3d model using min3d framework?

Tags: android, exception, resources, live-wallpaper

I tried to load 3d object in my Live Wallpaper Application using min3d, but i have that exception: "E/AndroidRuntime(5989): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0".

I put "sunflower_obj" and "sunflower_mlt" files to "res/raw" folder, "sunflower.jpg" to "res/drawable" folder. Here is my code:

```
package com.electricpunch.wallpaper;

import min3d.core.Object3dContainer;
import min3d.objectPrimitives.ParticleSprite;
import min3d.parser.IParser;
import min3d.parser.Parser;
import min3d.wallpaper.CommonRender;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.util.Log;

public class TestRenderer extends CommonRender {

    private Context mContext;
    private float mCameraPosition;

    private Object3dContainer objModel;

    public TestRenderer(Context _context) {
        super(_context);
        this.mContext = _context;
        mCameraPosition = 0.5f;

    }

    @Override
    public void initScene() {
        IParser parser = Parser.createParser(Parser.Type.OBJ, mContext.getResources(), "com.electricpunch.wallpaper:raw/sunflower_obj", true);
        parser.parse();
        objModel = parser.getParsedObject();
        objModel.scale().x = objModel.scale().y = objModel.scale().z = .7f;
        scene.addChild(objModel);

    }

    @Override
    public void updateScene() {
        objModel.rotation().x++;
        objModel.rotation().z++;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchUp(int x, int y) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Touch");
    }

    @Override
    public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset, float xStep, float yStep, int xPixels, int yPixels) {
        mCameraPosition = xOffset;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you clean the project after inserting, maybe there is a problem for accessing the inserted raw object. And maybe you just try to use a name that isn't combined with underline.

Answer (score 1):

use **sunflower_mtl** instead of **sunflower_mlt**

Since you got a ResourceNotFound-Exception i would also check texture references in mtl+obj.
it should be something like *"newmtl sunflower.jpg", "map_Kd sunflower.jpg", "mtllib sunflower_mtl", "usemtl sunflower.jpg"*.